# App Monthly active users from 1.1M to 0

Tags: facebook, firebug

All my Apps MAU are showing 0 - is this a bug facebook is fixing? Is anybody else having the same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Insights - not updating - no new data since the 18th](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7184759/facebook-insights-not-updating-no-new-data-since-the-18th)

Answer (score -1):

There has been a bug over the past few days, where Facebook hasn't updated their insights (since the 18th).  Likely the insights server stuck and needs to be awakened by a Facebook employee.  Wouldn't be too concerned about this, it will fix itself soon enough.

Comment: lol @ "Likely the insights server stuck and needs to be awakened by a Facebook employee" Thanks for the response. It is showing up now.